# Get the short Git version hash

Tags: git

Is there a cleaner way to get the short version hash of `HEAD` from Git?

I want to see the same output as I get from:

```
 git log -n 1 | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/^commit //' | head -c 8
```

---

I originally used the above command to generate a version string, but this is even better:

```
git describe --tags
```

It will output strings like `0.1.12` (tagged commit) or `0.1.11-5-g0c85fbc` (five commits after the tag).

Comment: Since you seem to be good at manipulating data with pipes and whatnot, you should know about [git aliases](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases). In this case, there is a command for what you want (see answers) but eventually you will find something where there is not, and aliases are great for that.

Comment: @[MatrixFrog](http://stackoverflow.com/users/65977/matrixfrog) thanks for the tip! I already did have some simple git aliases, but I didn't know just how powerful they can be until now. I especially like the graphviz display.

Comment: Huh. When I run `git describe --tags` I get the message, _"fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything."_.

Comment: @QuinnComendant You probably need to tag something first for `--tags` to work. Try [creating a tag first](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging); e.g. `git tag 1.0.0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git get short hash from regular hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413373/git-get-short-hash-from-regular-hash)

Answer (score 1110, accepted):

Try this:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

The command `git rev-parse` can do a remarkable number of different things, so you'd need to go through [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) very carefully to spot that though.

Comment: you can do the reverse and get the long commit hash from the short commit hash by doing the following ```git rev-parse HEAD```

Comment: The command also works with long rev IDs that are copy-pasted from the other sources like `git log`, eg `git rev-parse --short 97dd2ae065771908ee9ae0fa08ccdb58b5a6b18f` returns `97dd2ae`

Comment: It just works with references. You can use HEAD, tag names, branch names or plain hashes.

Comment: Warning, this returns a 7 character commit hash (by default) while many places like gitlab use 8 characters!

Comment: You can use `git rev-parse --short=8 HEAD` to get the 8 character length that is used by GitLab. You can also set `core.abbrev` to 8 for a specific git repo with a command like `git config core.abbrev 8` [Source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---shortlength)

Comment: At Ubuntu 20.04 `git rev-parse --short=7 ...` returns 8 charecters for me. even if I put `--short=6` or less - it returns 8!!

Comment: Also important to know is that the number you provide to `--short=n` is just a _minimum_. It may return a longer string in order to guarantee that hash points to a unique commit. From [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---shortlength): "[it] shortens the object name to a unique prefix with at least `length` characters".

Answer (score 167):

You can do just about any format you want with `--pretty=format:`

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:%h
```

The meaning of `%h`, from `man git log`, is:

> `%h`
> abbreviated commit hash

To see other format options, see `man git log` and search for the section that begins with the phrase "*Placeholders that expand to information extracted from the commit:*".

Answer (score 123):

```
git log -1 --abbrev-commit
```

will also do it.

```
git log --abbrev-commit
```

will list the log entries with abbreviated SHA-1 checksum.

Comment: Also works with `git log --pretty=oneline`, which unlike `--oneline`, otherwise prints full size hashes.

Comment: this seems a lot cleaner than pretty format.

Answer (score 74):

A simple way to see the Git commit short version and the Git commit message is:

```
git log --oneline
```

Note that this is shorthand for

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

Comment: --oneline is the best option

Comment: @JuanIgnacioBarisich the best option depends on how much information you need to view. In case one needs more information like author or date then git log --abbrev-commit would be a better option.
also log --pretty might be a better option to choose which information to log

Answer (score 42):

A really simple way is to:

```
git describe --always
```

Comment: ha, sweet, that addresses the cases where git describe will fail otherwise (because describe expects a tag somewhere in history)  thx

Comment: Not good if you strictly want the short hash - since this can return an annotated tag is there is one.

Comment: In some cases `git describe --long` could help. From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe#Documentation/git-describe.txt---long): "Always output the long format (the tag, the number of commits and the abbreviated commit name) *even when it matches a tag*." [my emphasis]

Comment: Using `--long` is better but sometimes you get a short hash and sometimes 3 items separated by hyphens. These days, I use the accepted answer. Back in the day, I didn't know about annotated tags — perhaps they didn't even exist!

Answer (score 23):

I have Git version 2.7.4 with the following settings:

```
git config --global log.abbrevcommit yes
git config --global core.abbrev 8
```

Now when I do:

```
git log --pretty=oneline
```

I get an abbreviated commit id of eight digits:

```
ed054a38 add project based .gitignore
30a3fa4c add ez version
0a6e9015 add logic for shifting days
af4ab954 add n days ago
...
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Vote for my question too!

Answer (score 21):

Branch with short hash and last comment:

```
git branch -v

  develop      717c2f9 [ahead 42] blabla
* master       2722bbe [ahead 1] bla
```

Answer (score 8):

what about this :

```
git log --pretty="%h %cD %cn %s"
```

it shows someting like :

674cd0d Wed, 20 Nov 2019 12:15:38 +0000 Bob commit message

see the [pretty format documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you need to get short commit SHA from the remote repository you can use the next command:

```
git ls-remote https://some.domain/some-remote-repo.git HEAD | awk '{ print substr($1,1,8) }'
```