# Maven BuildNumber plugin : how to get short hash

Tags: git, maven, build

Is there any way to configure the buildNumber plugin with git as SCM provider in order to get the short commit id.
Actually, this plugin work fine, but the id is too long : `b0c1c69be579175e63eeb1c056d607f01ab61e96`

I would like to have the shorter version : `b0c1c69`
With git command line it can be done with

```
 git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

As described [Get the short git version hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694389/get-the-short-git-version-hash)

Comment: I have made a patch for maven-buildNumber plugin and submitted it to the project [JIRA-link](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MBUILDNUM-86). The improvement concerns only Git SCM. Normally, from the next release **1.1** of the plugin, there will be a new configuration keyword `<shortRevisionLength>LENGTH</shortRevisionLength>`, where `LENGTH` is an integer - the length of a commit ID.

Comment: more information about this improvement you can find http://yevgen-fr.blogspot.com/2012/02/maven-buildnumber-plugin-short-revision.html

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43375126/54745