# Possible to extract the git repo revision hash via Python code?

Tags: python, git, version

Are there any easy ways to grab the git repository (on GitHub) version hash with Python code?  I want to use this to handle versioning of 'dev' releases of my software on github.

Comment: GutHub or Git repositories? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694389/get-the-short-git-version-hash

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear, I meant git repositories (I store them on github).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

gitproc = Popen(['git', 'show-ref'], stdout = PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = gitproc.communicate()

for row in stdout.split('\n'):
    if row.find('HEAD') != -1:
        hash = row.split()[0]
        break

print hash
```

Answer (score 9):

```
def git_version():
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    gitproc = Popen(['git', 'rev-parse','HEAD'], stdout = PIPE)
    (stdout, _) = gitproc.communicate()
    return stdout.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```
import subprocess
ref = subprocess.check_output("""
    git 2>/dev/null show-ref | awk '/refs\/heads\/master/{print $1}'
""", shell=True)
print ref
```

Adapt it if you have something else than `master`

Comment: Via python. run the `git` command via `Popen` and parse the output in python.

Comment: No need to pipe it to awk.  Just read `stdout` from the `Popen` object and parse the text in Python. Python is very good as string handling!

Comment: Sorry, had to go with tMC's answer.  check_output is from 2.7, I'de like backwards compatibility for now.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/) for this.