# How to generate a 10 alphanumeric String?

Tags: java, uuid, referrals

I want to create a link like http://www.mywebsite/**i3DfdgSdec**. This link must be unique by registered user in my application. I don't know how to generate a unique ( or with the less error collision probability) on 10 alphanumeric ?

Comment: Make user name unique and add that name there.

Comment: This url must be shareable on internet. So if the username is visible people could use them to try to login.

Comment: Don't you have password

Comment: create a hash using some common hash algorithm (eg. SHA) and use the first 10  bytes.

Comment: I cannot provide user's username of my application on internet. I will increase security risk. hackers could use this username and guess password

Comment: @ThomasKilian I think i could have collision problem. No ?

Comment: @Pracede see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134627/how-much-of-a-git-sha-is-generally-considered-necessary-to-uniquely-identify-a

Comment: Why don't you use a sequence number to identify all of your users? Using just numbers, that would allow a unique number per people on earth.

Comment: A collision with a SHA is possible but unlikely. You could hold the used hashes in a table and add additional salt to create a different one.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestion. I write a class to generate alpha numeric string. I ensure my self in database to avoid birthday problem