# How does Git create unique commit hashes, mainly the first few characters?

Tags: git, algorithm, hash, git-hash

I find it hard to wrap my head around how Git creates fully unique hashes that aren't allowed to be the same even in the first 4 characters. I'm able to call commits in Git Bash using only the first four characters. Is it specifically decided in the algorithm that the first characters are "ultra"-unique and will not ever conflict with other similar hashes, or does the algorithm generate every part of the hash in the same way?

Comment: [a-z], [A-Z] and [0-9] are possible values for characters. You have 72 * 72 * 72 *72 unique options for 4 characters. If you have more than 26873856 commits, maybe you should think about your project again (if you'll be alive).

Comment: But how does the algorithm make sure that there will never be a commit hash with the first 5 characters the same as another?

Comment: @MarounMaroun 26+26+10 != 72 :-) but your point is right.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/masak/2415865

Comment: @Ben there is no guarantee that the first 4 or 5 or whatever characters you prefer produce an unique sequence. It is just an observation that, for most repositories, 5 or 6 characters are enough to unique identify an object in the repository (be it a commit or other internal object). Larger repositories need 7 characters (but they contain millions of objects).

Comment: It happens that an older [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18134627/4265352) is popular at this moment. Read it and its answers for explanation.

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405922/in-my-repo-how-long-must-the-longest-hash-prefix-be-to-prevent-any-overlap

Comment: As I mention in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43312106/6309) and in more detail with "[Why doesn't Git use more modern SHA?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838703/6309)", SHA1 will soon be only one of the possible hashes to use with Git.

Comment: @Marcoun git hashes are all lowercase and only use [a-f] and [0-9], and the OP spoke of 4 characters not 5, so it's really more like 16 * 16 * 16 * 16 which is 65536.  Collisions in first 4 chars are uncommon but certainly possible, in which case you just specify more chars.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Git uses the following information to generate the sha-1:

- The source tree of the commit (which unravels to all the subtrees and
  blobs)
- The parent commit sha1
- The author info (with timestamp)
- The committer info (right, those are different!, also with timestamp)
- The commit message

(on the complete explanation; look [here](https://gist.github.com/masak/2415865)).

Git **does NOT** guarantee that the first 4 characters will be unique. In [chapter 7 of the Pro Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Short-SHA-1) it is written:

> Git can figure out a short, unique abbreviation for your SHA-1 values.
>   If you pass --abbrev-commit to the git log command, the output will
>   use shorter values but keep them unique; it defaults to using seven
>   characters but makes them longer if necessary to keep the SHA-1
>   unambiguous:

So Git just makes the abbreviation **as long as necessary** to remain unique. They even note that:

> Generally, eight to ten characters are more than enough to be unique
>   within a project.
>
> As an example, the Linux kernel, which is a pretty large project with
>   over 450k commits and 3.6 million objects, has no two objects whose
>   SHA-1s overlap more than the first 11 characters.

So in fact they just depend on the great **improbability** of having the exact same (X first characters of a) sha.

Comment: So in theory: If there aren't enough characters to make the non-abbreviated hash unique, it makes every hash longer? I assume the hash is stored under a unique ID and the hash is only used for calling convenience.

Comment: the real sha is 20 bytes long. git log --abbrev-commit will just abreviate this sha to the X first characters. So in many cases the first 4 characters will suffice to indicate the correct commit, but if not git will show the first 5, 6, 7, ... characters of the sha

Comment: @Ben If two commits have the same hash, then git breaks down. Git relies on the collision-resistance of SHA-1. (In practice, if you encounter such a collision, which I believe has never occurred outside of intentional attempts to create collisions), you can just add a space to the end of the commit message, which will generate a new hash.

Comment: @RaymondChen maybe adding a space isn't even necessary, since the timestamp of the commit is also used in the generation of the hash. Just creating the same commit again, but a little later will suffice

Comment: @ChrisMaes, since the commit message is also used to generate the commit hash, what will happen to the commit id when someone edits the commit message (.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG) before pushing to remote?

Comment: @ChrisMaes, and the same questions as above when we ammend (--amend) the edit.

Comment: @PHcoDer as you might expect from my answer: the commit hash will change in both cases.

Comment: @ChrisMaes, yes it should. But I don't see that. What will trigger that change? I edited the file .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG saved it and the hash didn't change. So, it should be changing at the time of push? Or next amend to the commit?

Comment: @PHcoDer I don't see in what case you should edit the `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` file. If you run `git commit --amend` and you edit the message, then you will see that the hash changes.

Answer (score 12):

Apr. 2017: Beware that after the all [shattered.io episode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42450327/6309) (where a SHA1 collision was achieved by Google), the 20-byte format won't be there forever.

A first step for that is to replace `unsigned char sha1[20]` which is hard-code all over the Git codebase by a generic object whose definition might change in the future (SHA2?, [Blake2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAKE_(hash_function)), ...)

See [commit e86ab2c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e86ab2c1cd60ec4b9214e5cd8450a474fa175f5c) (21 Feb 2017) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).

> Convert the remaining uses of `unsigned char [20]` to `struct object_id`.

That is an example of an ongoing effort started with [commit 5f7817c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f7817c85d4b5f65626c8f49249a6c91292b8513) (13 Mar 2015) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204), for v2.5.0-rc0, in [`cache.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b14f27f91770e0f99f64135348977a0ce1c7993a/cache.h#L65-L71):

```
/* The length in bytes and in hex digits of an object name (SHA-1 value). */
#define GIT_SHA1_RAWSZ 20
#define GIT_SHA1_HEXSZ (2 * GIT_SHA1_RAWSZ)

struct object_id {
    unsigned char hash[GIT_SHA1_RAWSZ];
};
```

And don't forget that, even with SHA1, the 4 first characters are no longer enough to guarantee uniqueness, as I explain in "[How much of a git sha is *generally* considered necessary to uniquely identify a change in a given codebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015031/6309)".

---

**Update Dec. 2017** with Git 2.16 (Q1 2018): this effort to support an alternative SHA is underway: see "[Why doesn't Git use more modern SHA?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838703/6309)".

You will be able to use another hash: SHA1 is no longer the only one for Git.

**Update 2018-2019**: the choice has been made in Git 2.19+: **[SHA-256](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ed8d8da374f648764758f13038ca93af87ab800)**.
See "[**hash-function-transition**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/041f5ea1cf987a4068ef5f39ba0a09be85952064/Documentation/technical/hash-function-transition.txt)".

This is not yet active (meaning git 2.21 is still using SHA1), but the code is being done to support in the future SHA-256.

---

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), the work goes on, and uses "struct `object_id"` for replacing use of "`char *sha1`"

See [commit 2fecc48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2fecc48cade44529dff2594eadfb294643cdc24d), [commit 6ac9760](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ac9760a30683a24e80a7aefe30e383046e810f0), [commit b99b6bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b99b6bcc57faf5c989fc18c3b8d4d92df3407cec), [commit 63f4a7f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63f4a7fc0107ec240f48605a4d4f8e41b91caa41), [commit e31c710](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e31c71083abef5dbe4b4112a1a1a24a90ce587f3), [commit 500e4f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/500e4f236606684467b0b34b86e319dfa40747c4), [commit f66d4e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f66d4e025059b734ba8da40ec059bb0fb8991306), [commit a93c141](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a93c141ddef25dc999fff73c590b42d3af606ff3), [commit 3f83fd5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f83fd5e44c1f038c8a7033cb77399e9ef4f43a9), [commit 0763671](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0763671b8e0b3ef873df13c741a911b809e6813d) (24 Feb 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e8e7184](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e8e71848ea866d7dc34eacffc20b9c3826ae29a1), 05 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`packfile`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2fecc48cade44529dff2594eadfb294643cdc24d): drop `nth_packed_object_sha1()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> Once upon a time, `nth_packed_object_sha1()` was the primary way to get the oid of a packfile's index position.
> But these days we have the more type-safe `nth_packed_object_id()` wrapper, and all callers have been converted.

> Let's drop the "`sha1`" version (turning the safer wrapper into a single function) so that nobody is tempted to introduce new callers.

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), the "`sha1` to `oid`" rename continues..

See [commit a46d1f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a46d1f732192a8621ead7ea5c4a3ca391ad881cb), [commit fb07bd4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb07bd42975bcbfbc29d4a3ef1bff1039a469336), [commit cfaf9f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfaf9f05c6174b520082036c0f1439adf9c4fbf7), [commit ef2d554](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef2d5547fa342197befd4be599438d7a7fa41e04), [commit 962dd7e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/962dd7ebc3e76afc2c896d377c319f8140966303), [commit 8f7e3de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f7e3de0970c419688f23f505b5cb7a9690d9b09), [commit b1f1ade](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b1f1ade87be595b5854c82850658c80465fdb16b) (27 Sep 2020) by [Martin Ågren (`none`)](https://github.com/none).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 07601b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/07601b5b360264a74f94d74640999ea19cf61517), 05 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`wt-status`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b1f1ade87be595b5854c82850658c80465fdb16b): replace sha1 mentions with oid
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Martin Ågren</sup>

> `abbrev_sha1_in_line()` uses a `struct` object_id `oid` and should be fully prepared to handle non-SHA1 object ids. Rename it to `abbrev_oid_in_line()`.
>
> A few comments in `wt_status_get_detached_from()` mention "sha1". The variable they refer to was renamed in [e86ab2c1cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e86ab2c1cd60ec4b9214e5cd8450a474fa175f5c) ("wt-status: convert to struct `object_id",` 2017-02-21, Git v2.13.0-rc0). Update the comments to reference "`oid`" instead.