# git history simulate a merge in history without altering ids or adding virtual commit parent in public branches

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitolite

### How to add a virtual commit parent without changing commit id of child ?

Given a git repository (stored in an GitLab-Instance and for some reason on an other server in gitolite - both Servers inhouse) with that structure for public access on GitHub:

```
o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-m-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-  origin Master
         /   \   \F-o-o-o-o-o-o-o           origin feature 
o-o-o-o-o-o-o-O                             origin oldthing
```

There are some documentations about `git rebase`, `git replace`, `git replace --graft`, `git commit --amend` and `GraftPoints`: But I am not realy sure about how to use them so that the first commit in `feature` (`F`) gets a second parent (i.e.) the last commit in `oldthing` (`O`). 
In best case no commit id should change, but it is acceptable if the commit Id for the first commit in `feature' will change.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

@Chris is 100% accurate in how he describes how git hashes are constructed. (Though the tangent on collisions simply confuses the issue.)

You can use [git replace](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-replace.html) to make the first commit of `feature` *appear* to have a second parent of the last commit of `oldthing`. But that would have to be done on the client-side, per-clone, not on the server side.

You can also do some sort of rebase to rebase `feature` onto a merge of `m` and `O`. It would be something like this (untested)

```
git checkout O
git merge m
rm -Rf *
git checkout -- F
git add .
git commit -C F
git rebase --onto HEAD m feature # This command probably isn't quite right. Some experimenting required.
```

Comment: Fair point about talking too much about hash collisions. I've edited my answer to mention them only in passing.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not realy sure about how to use them so that the first commit in `feature` get a second parent (i.e.) the last commit in `oldthing`. In best case no commit id should change, but it is acceptable if the commit Id for the first commit in `feature' will change.

[Commit hashes are generated from a number of inputs including the parent commit hash(es)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34764586/354577). Adding another parent to the first commit in `feature` will change its hash, which will cause the hashes of all descendant commits to change.

This is a fundamental part of how Git works. What you want to do is impossible¹.

---

¹Hash collisions are possible but *extremely* unlikely. In practice there is currently no way to generate an arbitrary hash collision.