# Dynamically Replace git comment value with git commit id?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

Is it possible to inject the git commit reivision in the comments ,
means
The git commit id ..
e.g in the file comments we will have git revision : $gitrevision
when you merge $gitrevision ,
It should get replaced by the actual commit id from git .

Is there any way for that , any help is appreciated ..

Comment: Why do you want to have the commit hash itself in the message?

Answer (score 4):

I think it is not possible because the commit id or hash is made of a few things and one of them is the commit message.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34764586/7395911) a nice answer from another question on StackOverflow, where it states all the things used to make a commit hash, which are:

> Git uses the following information to generate the sha-1:
>
> - The source tree of the commit (which unravels to all the subtrees and blobs)
> - The parent commit sha1
> - The author info (with timestamp)
> - The committer info (right, those are different!, also with timestamp)
> - **The commit message**

The last one being what you're trying to use after the hash is generated.

Comment: Yes. To check it by yourself, just use `git cat-file -p <hash>` on any commit and you'll see exactly **what** constitutes the commit (the info listed in the answer here).