# Select rows using part of UUID4

Tags: postgresql

I have table of users with UUIDv4 as primary key.
How can I select all rows with id starting with 'e2eb5'?

I tried following select:

```
SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE "id" LIKE 'e2eb5%';
```

In my application there are less than one thousand users and first part of UUID should be just all info you need to identify them.

Therefore I want user detail to be on url like this:

`/users/e2eb5`

Instead of:

`/users/3b0fbfd6-0661-4880-b5c5-4659ed85fa96`

Edit:

Querying it as suggested here: [How to query UUID for postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549747/how-to-query-uuid-for-postgres)

```
where some_uuid between 'e99aec55-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
                and 'e99aec55-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff'
```

is not viable solution as it requires either fixed length of uuid prefix or writing more complex query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query UUID for postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549747/how-to-query-uuid-for-postgres)

Comment: You could try converting `id` to text and comparing it that way. `... WHERE "id"::text LIKE 'e2eb5%';`. Can lose performance with tons of rows, but I think should be okay with less than 1,000 rows.

Comment: @trs Works great! Post it as your answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the `id` to `text` and compare how you have in your question.

```
SELECT *
FROM "user"
WHERE "id"::text LIKE 'e2eb5%';
```

This needs to convert each row's `id` to text, so it can be slow with tons or rows. But working with less than 1,000 should be fine.