# Git cherry-pick and sha-1 value

Tags: git, sha1, cherry-pick

In https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project is example that shows how to cherry pick on a branch. In this example the sha-1 value of commit is used in full length?

`$ git cherry-pick e43a6fd3e94888d76779ad79fb568ed180e5fcdf`

Doesn't the cherry-pick allow short sha-1 values like e43a6, so that the following is valid?

`$ git cherry-pick e43a6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but the provided SHA snippet has to identify unique refspec.
Take a look here: [How much of a git sha is *generally* considered necessary to uniquely identify a change in a given codebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134627/how-much-of-a-git-sha-is-generally-considered-necessary-to-uniquely-identify-a)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the short value anywhere you can use the long hash. Not sure about the intent behind the doc using the full hash, but `git cherry-pick e43a6` works too.

Guideline on short hash:

> The full SHA-1 object name (40-byte hexadecimal string), or a leading
>   substring that is unique within the repository. E.g.
>   dae86e1950b1277e545cee180551750029cfe735 and dae86e both name the same
>   commit object if there is no other object in your repository whose
>   object name starts with dae86e.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions

Bonus:

Default short hash is 7 character in length:

```
git rev-parse --short e43a6fd3e94888d76779ad79fb568ed180e5fcdf
e43a6fd
```