# How do I see the Git commit id in TortoiseGit log

Tags: tortoisegit

When I look at my repo login Git on the web (GitLab), there is a Commit ID for each commit

e.g.

```
Commit e7123ff4  authored 1 month ago by xxxx
```

When I look at the log using TortoiseGit I cannot see this ID - How can I see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the pane below the tree - there should be a line `SHA-1: e7123ff4...`
(e7123ff4 is an abbreviation of the full commit id)

https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html

Comment: ah, I did that, but I didn't know/notice that the one in GitLab was only an abbrevation! Thanks!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134627/how-much-of-a-git-sha-is-generally-considered-necessary-to-uniquely-identify-a may be of interest...

Answer (score 2):

The Commit ID (often also called SHA-1) is always displayed above the log message in the log dialog for a selected revision (in your case look for the `SHA-1: e7123ff4...` line; on GitLab/GitHub this is often abbreviated).

Also, it is possible to display a SHA-1 column so that you can see them all without selecting a revision. This can be done by opening the context menu on the column headers.

[image: TortoiseGit Log Dialog]

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html