# How to get the short sha for the github workflow?

Tags: git, docker, github-actions

I am creating a workflow in GitHub which creates and uses a docker image. Therefore I have started my workflow file with a global environment variable for this docker image which is visible for all the jobs in my workflow:

```
name: continuous integration
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'

env:
  IMAGE: docker.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository }}/jactor-persistence:${{ github.sha }}
```

I want to replace `${{ github.sha }}` with the short sha of the head commit, the same as the result of the following command `git rev-parse --short HEAD`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

As VonC mentioned, you can just compute the string yourself in a previous step.

```yaml
      - name: Set outputs
        id: vars
        run: echo "sha_short=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Check outputs
        run: echo ${{ steps.vars.outputs.sha_short }}
```

Comment: Good addition to my answer. The problem is knowing that 7 is short enough, and not too short: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015031/6309

Comment: Does `git rev-parse --short` vary to make it unique? I can't quite tell from the documentation.

Comment: Yet it does: that is what https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015031/6309 documents/illustrates.

Comment: Thanks. I've made that the answer instead of selecting the first 7 characters.

Comment: Great answer, but this fails to work correctly when run on windows. Need to quote the echo string.
`echo "::set-output name=sha_short::$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)"`

Comment: Thanks @MaxGhost. Updated the answer.

Comment: Oh also - worth mentioning that the commit hash on HEAD during a PR will actually refer to a merge commit that is the result of merging the PR branch into the target branch. CI runs on that merge to ensure that the build wouldn't be broken even when taking into account possible merge conflicts. It's the right commit hash when CI is run on the mainline branch though. Usually not a problem, but it might be for you depending on the usecase.

Comment: In addition to @MaxGhost's comment, if you want latest commit's hash of the branch instead of merge commit: `echo "::set-output name=sha_short::$(git rev-parse --short ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }})"`

Comment: BE CAREFUL! The HEAD will be changed when you merge a branch to other branches (like merge hotfix/ to both `main` and `develop`) branches. In my case:


The `sha_short` was "9b2aaa1"
The `GITHUB_SHA` was "715a576"
The `github.sha` was "715a576"

Comment: set-output is deprecated. use this instead: `echo "sha_short=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`

Comment: Also as @Coder1 mentioned, set-output will be [potentially] deprecated on 31st May 2023. You can also set new envvars like 
`echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` to reference them as outputs.
`echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_ENV` to reference them as env vars.

Comment: `echo "SHORT=$(echo ${{ github.sha }} | cut -c1-7)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` seems the cleanist.

Comment: Just in case I'm not misunderstanding things here. If I would like to get the latest short commit SHA from a Pull request within gh-actions would I use the example @Yoon-JaeJeong provided?

Comment: This will not correctly on Windows based runner, which uses powershell as the default shell. `echo "sha_short=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT` should in used instead for Windows runner. You can use `if: runner.os == "Windows"` to run a command for Windows only, while using `if: runner.os != "Windows"` to run a command for non Windows runners.

Answer (score 49):

You can also set an environment variable with the short sha:

```
    - name: Add SHORT_SHA env property with commit short sha
      run: echo "SHORT_SHA=`echo ${GITHUB_SHA} | cut -c1-8`" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

`SHORT_SHA` can then be used like any other environment variable, e.g. like this:

```
    - name: My step
      run: myscript ${SHORT_SHA}
```

Comment: I liked this approach, but used rev-parse instead `run: echo "SHORT_SHA=\`git rev-parse --short HEAD\`" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

Comment: I ended up using this approach because `git rev-parse --short HEAD` stopped working for me and was blank. I used `${{ github.sha }}` instead as well.

Answer (score 44):

Found a possible solution [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127230307/https://github.community/t/add-short-sha-to-github-context/16418), using bash's [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

```yaml
- name: Step
  run: echo ${GITHUB_SHA::7}
```

Comment: this is still something (it seems) that you need to run in a step somehow... even though it seems quite simple, it seems that it is not possible to do as a global variable...

Comment: @jactor-rises what you are looking for is not possible at the moment, unless github adds short sha to variable/context, so currently, shortest is the best IMO

Answer (score 7):

This works on Windows:

```
- name: Get short SHA
  run: echo "SHORT_SHA=$("${{ github.sha }}".SubString(0, 8))" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV

- name: Print short SHA
  run: echo "Short SHA is ${{ env.SHORT_SHA }}"
```

Comment: Requires powershell (the default on windows workflows).

Answer (score 3):

It does not seem to be available: the [`github` context](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) only includes `github.sha` as the *full* commit sha (that triggered the workflow run)

You would need to somehow compute the string you want (by selecting only the first n characters of `${{ github.sha }}`.

That means you can:

- define a variable as shown in [`peterevans`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11934042/peterevans)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59819441/6309)
- write it to the disk
- `cat $my_var` to use your `VAR` in every step

See [`actions/starter-workflows` issue 68](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/issues/68#issuecomment-524937002) and [examples](https://github.com/firepress-org/rclone-in-docker/tree/master/.github/workflows).

But [since Oct. 2019](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/issues/80#issuecomment-537560905), you now have "[Env at the workflow and job level](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-10-01-github-actions-new-workflow-syntax-features/#env-at-the-workflow-and-job-level)"

> It is common to need define a set of environment variables that are used in multiple steps in a job and even multiple jobs in a workflow.
>
> Now you can **add an `env` map at both the workflow and job level**.
> Those environment variables will be merged with the `env` defined at any step lower in the hierarchy.

See:

- [workflow `env`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env)
- [job `env`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenv)

Comment: yes... this is what I came to a conclusion myself. But is this possible to do in a expression in the global variable (in here somewhere`${{ github.sha }}`), to avoid to duplicate this all places which is in need of the variable

Comment: @jactor-rises Sure sure about global, but peterevans's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59819441/6309) uses a variable.

Comment: .... I now that, but I would like to have a global env. variable to avoid duplicating code in my jobs...

Comment: @jactor-rises That would be using an env map: see my edited answer above.

Comment: yes... and I am using workflow environment (`env` at the top of the workflow file) so it is available to all my jobs in the workflow. But at the workflow stage, is it possible to manipulate `${{ github.sha }}` to be the short sha, or do I have to duplicate this logic in my jobs?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [metadata-action](https://github.com/docker/metadata-action) to extract tags (and other metadata) from github events. From the metadata you can also get a short sha. Here is an example of jobs that extract short sha and subsequently use it to build a docker image:

```yaml
- name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
  id: meta
  uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
  with:
    images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ github.repository }}
    tags: |
      type=sha,format=short,prefix=

- name: Build and push Docker image
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
  with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
    labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

You don't need to use it to build a new image. It can be accessed in following jobs via `${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}`. Here meta is an id of job where the tags are defined.