# How to build short Git Sha in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

For a lookup I need the short sha of a Commit in mulitple steps in GitHub Actions.

So I tried:

```yaml
- env:
    SHORT_SHA: ${{ format('{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}', github.sha[0], github.sha[1], github.sha[2], github.sha[3], github.sha[4], github.sha[5], github.sha[6]) }}
  steps:
```

but the resulting string is empty.
Now I am out of ideas with which GitHub expression I can build a short sha.

Comment: Can you compute it during the commands in `run`? If so, use `git rev-parse --short HEAD`. If not, there's a couple of different techniques here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59810838/how-to-get-the-short-sha-for-the-github-workflow.