# get short sha of commit with gitpython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

The long SHA can be gotten like below:

```
repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True)
sha = repo.head.object.hexsha
```

Or, in git 3.1.7:

```
sha = repo.head.commit.hexsha
```

How about short one?
(short `SHA` is decided by the scale of the repo, so it should not be like `sha[:7]`)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the gitpython `Commit` object does not support the short sha directly.  However, you can use still gitpython's [support for calling git directly](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly) to retrieve it (as of git 3.1.7):

```
repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True)
sha = repo.head.commit.hexsha
short_sha = repo.git.rev_parse(sha, short=4)
```

This is the equivalent of running

```
git rev-parse --short=4 ...
```

on the command-line, which is [the usual way of getting the short hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413373/git-get-short-hash-from-regular-hash). This will return the shortest possible unambiguous hash of length >= 4 (You could pass in a smaller number, but since git's internal min is 4 it will have the same effect).

Comment: Thank you. actually, i don't want to use shell command, because it makes script run much more slowly.. maybe fixed length of hash does work in most cases, so i will use it.

Comment: Hmm... do you mean shelling out yourself directly or using the git-command database internal to `gitpython`?  Using `repo.git.revparse()` like I suggested does the latter, and should be really fast.  If your concern is the memory consumption or spawning new procs, you can instead use `git.Repo(odbt=GitDB)` for a pure-python solution, though it runs 2-5 times slower.

Comment: It seems that `repo.head.object.hexsha` does not call shell command, and this is ideal one. because I'm correcting git status information to display it in shell prompt. (so it should be fast)

Comment: > "Using repo.git.revparse() like I suggested does the latter"                           really. I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: Actually, small correction; looks like if you are using python > 2.4, it will default to `gitdb`, which is pure-python, but in any event, using `repo.git` will still run commands via `Popen`.  Still internal to gitpython though

Comment: So, without Popen, it is impossible to get shortened hash. I'm using fixed length. thanks.

Comment: This answer should define the `sha` variable like @mu did below in order to be complete

Comment: As someone also mentioned there is a way of doing it https://stackoverflow.com/a/63453759/99834

Comment: @sorin As per [gitpython 3.17 documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.objects.commit) `commit.hexsha` still returns the full 40 byte hex version rather than the short version -- I think `git.rev_parse()` remains the valid way to do this. I've added how to get at the long sha in the latest gitpython

Answer (score 6):

You will need to use the `short` argument of `rev-parse` here to generate the smallest SHA that can uniquely identify the commit. Basically, the `short` will call the internal git API and return the shortest possible length string for the SHA which can uniquely identify the commit, even if you've passed a very small value for short. So effectively, you can do something like below, which will give you the shortest SHA always (I use `short=1` to emphasize that):

```
In [1]: import git
In [2]: repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True)
In [3]: sha = repo.head.object.hexsha
In [4]: short_sha = repo.git.rev_parse(sha, short=1)
In [5]: short_sha
Out[5]: u'd5afd'
```

You can read [more about this from the git side here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015031/1860929). Also, as mentioned in the [man-page for git-rev-parse](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html), --short will by default take 7 as its value, and minimum 4.

> `--short=number`
>
> Instead of outputting the full SHA-1 values of object names try to abbreviate them to a shorter unique name. When no length is specified 7 is used. The minimum length is 4.

Answer (score 5):

For gitpython 3.1.15, there seems to be a shorter way of getting the hash compared [to the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31957429/2745495).

You can simply do

```py
hash = repo.git.rev_parse(repo.head, short=True)
```

You do not need explicitly obtain

```py
sha = repo.head.commit.hexsha
```

first.

Comment: You can also use `repo.git.rev_parse('HEAD', short=True)`.

Answer (score 3):

actually, you need to use

```
short_sha = repo.git.rev_parse(sha, short=True)
```

short=4 always shows 4 letter hash even in my ginormous git base

Comment: From the [`git-rev-parse` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse):

"--short[=length]
Same as --verify but shortens the object name to a unique prefix with at least length characters. The minimum length is 4, the default is the effective value of the core.abbrev configuration variable (see git-config[1])."

Presumably you are getting 4 length hashes because it is still unique in your repo

Answer (score -1):

The answers already supplied assume you are calling rev-parse through the shell, which is slow. If you already have a reference to the repo, you can do this by accessing the name_rev property on the Commit object with string truncation as follows. The reference is fixed at the length you supply (here, 8), but it works:

```
repo.remotes.origin.refs['my/branch/name'].object.name_rev[:8]
```

The actual output of this command is the full sha, followed by a space, followed by the branch name.

Comment: I don't know what answers you are talking about since literally not a single one calls it through the shell. This solution is also pretty bad because it uses a fixed length of the commit hash which does not have the uniqueness property the rev_parse solution has.

Comment: @StefanFabian the answers that mention `repo.git` end up calling it through the shell under the hood: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly

Comment: Ah sorry, you are right! The point that you might need more than 8 characters to preserve uniqueness still stands but I'd like to apologize for the tone. Apart from this, performance-wise this is a great solution.

Answer (score -1):

Current answer is outdated and the way to retrie sha of the commit is `commit.hexsha`.

Comment: This is not a standalone answer to the question of getting a short hash, and is really only relevant as a comment on the outdated answer mentioned.